# Java Angular JWT implementation

Tags: jwt

I'd like to hear some opinions about my JWT authentication flow.

Whereas

if I store the token in local/session storage, XSS attacks are possible,
if I store the token in a cookies http only / secure, CRSF attacks are possible.

My solution is to split the token into two parts, one to put in cookie and one to put in local storage and pass back to the server with header. The back-end joins the parts and validates the request.

Is this a correct implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it into two parts or you can verify that the token in the cookie matches the token from the local storage. If the token is too long, you can just store a UUID or some unique key in the cookie and the local storage instead. The server should expect the token and that the key in the cookie matches the key in the local storage.

See [Double Submit Cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) in OWASP.